# Combine lines after grep -B

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep, text-formatting

I'm trying to parse some data from a log file.
The premises are that i need a date that is 2 lines above the the line with the pattern that i want.

I'm able to reach this with grep:

```
> grep -B2 "rc_transaction result=" xml.log
```

And the output is 3 lines for each pattern find:

```
03 Apr 12:48:42.503 [6086-16592] DEBUG c.q.q.d.server.XmlServlet - <?xml version="1.0"?>
<stream id="18561">
<rc_transaction result="ok" vst_time="2018-04-03 10:48:42.431" transaction_time="2018-04-03 10:48:42.497" sequence_number="117749" code="0">
--
03 Apr 12:49:21.936 [6086-16592] DEBUG c.q.q.d.server.XmlServlet - <?xml version="1.0"?>
<stream id="18566">
<rc_transaction result="ok" vst_time="2018-04-03 10:49:21.839" transaction_time="2018-04-03 10:49:21.930" sequence_number="117750" code="0">
--
03 Apr 12:49:39.654 [6086-16592] DEBUG c.q.q.d.server.XmlServlet - <?xml version="1.0"?>
<stream id="18569">
<rc_transaction result="ok" vst_time="2018-04-03 10:49:39.582" transaction_time="2018-04-03 10:49:39.648" sequence_number="117751" code="0">
```

Now, i need to parse this results an get the date on the first line and some properties from the third line, something like this:

```
03 Apr 12:48:42.503 result="ok" sequence_number="117749"
03 Apr 12:49:21.936 result="ok" sequence_number="117750"
03 Apr 12:49:39.654 result="ok" sequence_number="117751"
```

Whats the best method to achieve this?

Comment: It's not either of the timestamps in the actual XML that you are interested in then?

Comment: No. I need the time of when the transaction was processed (logged) and some data about it

Comment: @Kusalananda I understand now what you asked. The dates are different altough in the example they seem similar. But they can deffer on some minutes sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/<\?xml/{ date=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 }/rc_transaction result=/{ print date, $2, $7 }' xml.log
```

The output:

```
03 Apr 12:48:42.503 result="ok" sequence_number="117749"
03 Apr 12:49:21.936 result="ok" sequence_number="117750"
03 Apr 12:49:39.654 result="ok" sequence_number="117751"
```